# Virtual Command Prompt using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create a virtual command prompt using VB.Net (Visual Studio 2012).

I am trying to simulate the windows command prompt but in a virtual sense.

Has anyone tried to do something like this before?

Thank you in advance for your response and suggestions.

Edit: users will type commands into the command prompt and they will receive feedback depending on what they are trying to do. I will have a "help" command the user can enter and the command prompt will display everything the user is able to do. I am having trouble "styling" objects in visual basic to make them look and react like an actual command prompt.

Comment: Beyond the word "virtual" would you care to actually elaborate a little? What will this prompt do - what features of the standard command prompt do you want to share? What features do you want to change?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to embed a Console in a Windows Form application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20815881/how-to-embed-a-console-in-a-windows-form-application)

Comment: I have edited my question, thank you for the reply. Jens, That is almost exactly what I am looking for, it doesn't seem like they include the styling. I am going to work with the link you provided and update my question if I get it all working.